# How could I filter records by last item's time in Array

Tags: mongodb

Each record has history array, How could I get the last item in history that the item's 'updated_at' time should >= 3 hours ago?

I want to do this filter after the pre-process steps in `aggregation`

```
collection.aggregate(
      {"$match" => match_cond},

      ....
```

Thanks

## Document format

```
  "price": 2988.0,
  "history": [
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1441469169200),
      "price": 2988
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1441620011237),
      "price": 1558
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1441621596776),
      "price": 2988
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1441625059995),
      "price": 1558
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1441689121096),
      "price": 2988
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1441690782988),
      "price": 1558
    },
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1441695110834),
      "price": 2988
    }
  ],
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter results by the Last Array Entry Field Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835202/filter-results-by-the-last-array-entry-field-value)

Answer (score 0):

Do a $unwind, and then regroup if necessary.

```
collection.aggregate( [
    { $unwind: "history" },
    { 
       $match: { 
          "history.updated_at" : {
                $gt: ISODate("2015-09-17T10:00:00Z")
          }
       } 
    },
    { $group: { 
         _id : { 
             _id : "$_id",
             [ any fields except history ]
         },
         last_updated: { $last : "$history.updated_at"},
         last_price: { $last : "$history.price"}
     }} 
])
```